# Как удалить всё содержимое документа Word?

Tags: python, python-docx

С помощью dox пытаюсь сделать код для служебки в формате docx. Перед выгрузкой текста (параграфы и таблица), необходимо, чтобы шаблон очистился от предыдущей выгрузки. Пытался поюзать clear_content, но не могу понять, как его применить.

Comment: "чтобы шаблон очистился от предыдущей выгрузки"... а не сохранять файл с именем шаблона не пробовали?

Comment: Я думал об этом, но там утверждённый в конторе колонтитул (лого фирмы, реквизиты и др.)

Comment: читайте шаблон с колонтитулом, лого, реквизитами и т.д., заполняйте данными и сохраняйте, но под другим именем, чтоб шаблон оставался шаблоном для повторного использования...